# What are the colon and double forward-slash ( :// ) in URIs called?

Tags: url

What are the colon and double forward-slash ( `://` ) in URIs called?

Comment: You don't need to explicitly clarify that it's a "forward" slash. A "slash" is a "forward slash".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no special name for them.

The [URL specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3) generally describes them using symbols and just names everything *around* them.

> ```
>   URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
>
>   hier-part   = "//" authority path-abempty
>               / path-absolute
>               / path-rootless
>               / path-empty
> ```

At one point it does say:

> The authority component is preceded by a double slash

… which is as close as it gets to giving `//` a name.

Comment: ...and the first colon separates the scheme. They aren't a single entity.

Comment: Can we make names for them then? How about the Schemer for the colon and Lash-Lash for the two slashes? :D